# How to get permission for directly writing files to SD card from a PC

Tags: windows, file-transfer, file-management, android-pc

I need to manage my Android's files from PC with my mouse and keyboard, instead of do it on 5" and 7" touch screens. I did many tries with Google, but all options lead me to only one way:

1. From the PC, write the file to internal storage, (ex: Xender)
2. From Android, using an Android file manager (for example, ES File Explorer) to cut & paste the files to folders I want on the SD card.

The question is: **"How do I set permissions to directly write to the SD card from a PC?"**

I'm using Samsung Core Prime with Android 4.4.x (KitKat) and my PC's OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

Update:
I want to do it through Wi-Fi whenever I need instead of using a USB cable.
Below is a screenshot for clarifying my question:

[image]

Update:

Not only Xender, even ES Explorer can not write to extSDcard. Screenshot from my phone:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't MTP connection write files to external sdcard?

Comment: I lost my usb cable and dont want to buy other :) in other words, how can do it through wifi ?

Comment: You would need to connect locally to your SD card, for that you would need your computer and android to be connected to the same WiFi. Also I don't know of any explorer which connects through LAN for windows, so for that you will have to search on Google. It is just like using es explorer, to connect it to PC through LAN/WiFi and assessin accessing PC dikes on android. Just the same logic.

Comment: And also what program/explorer are you using in the screenshot?

Comment: is the android device rooted?

Comment: no it isn't, i dont know how to root. currently, i dont want root because the phone is in warranty duration

Comment: @Hunter: I'm using Xender.
Sure, my Android and my PC is on the same LAN. but i cant write file to android's SD card,

Comment: If you have LAN, so it must mean that you are accessing files through file sharing. I want to know

Comment: If you have LAN, so it must mean that you are accessing files through file sharing. I have used es explorer myself. And as I read your full post, it shouldn't happen. Use es explorer, clear it's data, update the app, then when you try to copy to SD card it will ask for permission and will rahe you to recent menu option, you can access the option bar on the right which wo let you chose your internal storage and SD card on the left.

Comment: So did it help?

Comment: Thanks @Hunter for reply, excuse me for late response, I off these recent days, I'll try your guide tonight and reply tomorrow.

Comment: not only my favorite Xender, ES Explorer can not write to SD card too. Refer this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67570

screenshot on my Phone: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipN5Xx5ypiGIg849LgU1vZgVkqSPg955sp5aNsXCQuWNOM5_spOTPscjW9ObKI5f5g?key=TDl1bkQxRm12WVpjMWpfa0g1RWZPc0VaU1dWWEpR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:
http://shareit.lenovo.com/

1. install [ShareIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.anyshare.gps) on Phone.
2. Install [ShareIt](http://shareit.lenovo.com/) on PC

Open ShareIt PC, choose "Connect to phone"
Open ShareIt on Android, choose "Connect to PC"
Enjoy.
The app support "Play to PC", "PPT control", "Remote view" and, **most important**, it support to get LARGE file from PC then save directly on extSDcard.

Comment: Broken link http://shareit.lenovo.com/

Answer (score 2):

@LongTTH

First of all, I'm not on Kitkat, but on Lollipop, just in case...

You can copy files from you PC to your phone through Xender, it works perfectly.

But first you must get rid of the annoying message in web.xender.com (that you are showing in your picture).

In fact you must do the authorisation process in Xender ON YOUR PHONE, you can't do it in your PC's browser.

- To do this, simply launch Xender on your phone, and go to Settings.
- Then in the first Menu, set the destination to SD Card. It will ask you to choose which Folder you want to point at.
- Simply choose SD Card, so all subfolders will be then authorized to work with Xender.

And voilà, you can now copy files directly from your PC to your SD Card, through Wifi and without any cable connection, and it's blazingly fast :-)

Comment: thanks for reply,
I'm on KitKat, and when I opent Xender's setting, in Storage Location, it's just has ONLY 1 option, "Phone storage". :( this just GOOGLE's rule, we can not breakit without root :(